# Probabilty Help

Tags: probability, independence, bayes-theorem

I need some help with these two probability questions:

> Cathy is trying to communicate information to George over a faulty network. The conveyed information is in the
> form of bits. The network is messy and so every ‘1’ that Cathy sends is received correctly with probability 0.8
> (so with probability 0.2 any ‘1’ sent by Cathy is received as a ‘0’ by George). Similarly, every ‘0’ sent by Cathy is
> received correctly with probability 0.7 (so with probability 0.3 the ‘0’ sent by Cathy is received as a ‘1’ by George).
> Suppose that Cathy is thrice as likely to send a ‘1’ as she is to send a ’0’.
>
> (a) Find the probability that George receives a ‘1’.
> (b) If George receives a ‘0’, find the probability that Cathy intended to send a ‘0’.

For part a, I would assume you would use the law of total probability, since there are two different scenarios, and each have a specific probability for George receiving a 1. However, I'm not sure how to set this up.

For part b, I would assume you would use the Bayes Rule, since you need to find a probaility of A given B occurs. I originally formatted A to be the probability Cathy intended to send George a '0', while B is the proability that George actually receives a ) from Cathy. However, I also had trouble setting this problem up.

Comment: Can  you compute the probability that $C$ sent a $1$?

Comment: Yes, your approaches are correct.  To get you started on part a:
$$P(\text{receiving a 1}) = P(\text{receiving a 1} \, | \, \text{sent a 1}) P(\text{sent a 1}) + P(\text{receiving a 1} \, | \, \text{sent a 0}) P(\text{sent a 0})$$
Write out the formula for Bayes rule in part b and see if you can do something similar.

Comment: @SherwinLott just wondering, when it says that Cathy is 3x as likely to send a '1' than '0', that means the probability of her sending a '1' is 75% right?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, if using Bayes's Theorem defeats your intuition, it may help to imagine a perfectly representative sample of cases.  Suppose that Cathy sends George $40$ bits.  (Why not Alice and Bob?  I don't know.)  Then she *tries* to send $30$ ones and $10$ zeros.  Of the $30$ ones, $24$ are received as ones and $6$ as zeros.  Of the $10$ ones, $7$ are received as zeros and $3$ as ones.

So George receives $24+3 = 27$ ones, of which $24$ were intentional, and $3$ were intended as zeros.  He also receives $6+7 = 13$ zeros, of which $7$ were intentional, and $6$ were intended as ones.  The desired probability for (a) is therefore $27/40$, and for (b) is therefore $7/13$.

Can you convert each of these concrete workings into the corresponding expressions involving total probability and Bayes's Theorem?